# How can I login to Facebook in IOS and share in news feed?

Tags: ios, facebook

I am using this code to share an item on Facebook newsfeed:

```
-(void)recommendOnFacebook:(Item *)currentItem{    
if(!facebook){
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"myappid" andDelegate:self];
} 
NSMutableDictionary *params2 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", currentItem.name], @"name",
                                [shop name], @"caption",
                                currentItem.description, @"description",
                                [NSString stringWithFormat:@""], @"link",
                                currentItem.imagePath, @"picture",
                                nil, @"actions",
                                nil];    
[facebook dialog:@"feed" 
     andParams:params2
     andDelegate:self];
}
```

If I am logged in, I can successfully see the dialog to share the feed. But if I am not logged in, after this code block finishes, api dialog asks for my credentials. What I need is, if the user is not logged in, api shows the dialog, after the user successfully logs in, another dialog is shown to continue sharing progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take a look at FBSessionDelegate. Here is my code for sharing

```
- (IBAction) facebookShare:(id)sender {
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    if (![delegate.facebook isSessionValid]) {
        [delegate.facebook authorize:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", @"offline_access", nil]];
    }
    else {
        NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
         [NSString stringWithFormat:@"TEXT", score.text], @"name",
         @"", @"caption",
         @"DESC.", @"description",
         @"link", @"link",
         @"imagelink", @"picture",
         nil];  
        [delegate.facebook dialog:@"feed"
               andParams:params
             andDelegate:self];
    }

}

#pragma mark - FB Session Delegate

- (void)fbDidLogin {
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    /*NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[delegate.facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[delegate.facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];*/
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
         [NSString stringWithFormat:@"TEXT", score.text], @"name",
         @"", @"caption",
         @"DESC.", @"description",
         @"link", @"link",
         @"imagelink", @"picture",
         nil];  
        [delegate.facebook dialog:@"feed"
               andParams:params
             andDelegate:self];
}
```

**EDIT**

For logout in cases of public cafe you need to make sure that u NEVER save access token in NSUSerDefaults as in FB Session delegate method fbDidLogin

Now implements FBDialogDelegate method

```
- (void)dialogDidComplete:(FBDialog *)dialog {
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [delegate.facebook logout:self];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I can share like that successfully. But I am using this application in a cafe, so every time the user shares something, it should logout. How can I do that? Any idea?

Comment: Yes, I am doing the same. But in the login page, it always says "You are logging into this app as "Burak". So the app remembers me. How can I avoid this? I don't set the access token to defaults.